# How I can output image from property?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

In my document type for my HomePage I have a MediaSelect property that holds my profile image. Over at the template I want to output this, but the following is no the right url?

```
<img src="@Umbraco.Field("profileImage")"
```

`profileImage` is the name of the property, so how can I get the correct url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the image in your razor file, get it like this:

```
@Umbraco.Media(CurrentPage.ProfileImage).UmbracoFile
```

Comment: Btw, this razor cheetsheet is pretty good! http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/razor-dynamicnode-cheat-sheet